# Postgres doesn't start (windows)

Tags: postgresql

This is a recurring problem I have.

Randomly Postgresql stops and receives no new connections (e.g., pgAdmin, SQuirrel).
I have to restart my computer a few times until the service starts successfully. 
When the service starts I have the following log:

```
2017-08-27 19:52:17 -03 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-08-27 19:52:17 -03 LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-08-27 18:17:21 -03
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1CD7CE8: wanted 24, got 0
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  redo is not required
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  sistema de banco de dados está pronto para aceitar conexões
2017-08-27 19:52:19 -03 LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I have an i7, 8GB and Windows 10. Today I use Postgresql 9.6

I have already installed different versions of Postgresql (9.4, 9.5), but I can not solve it.

Anyone have any ideas for solving the problem?

Log before error:

```
2017-08-27 18:16:52 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:16:52 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:16:52 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:17:24 -03 LOG:  could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
2017-08-27 18:26:53 -03 WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2017-08-27 18:27:53 -03 WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2017-08-27 18:28:53 -03 WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
...
2017-08-27 19:51:48 -03 ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Comment: You might want to check out the sibling site dba.StackExchange.com.

Comment: What is your **exact** Postgres version? (including the third digit).

Comment: Maybe something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38977119/330315

Comment: The current version is "PostgreSQL 9.6.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit". I checked this question @a_horse_with_no_name, but the problem occurs even without performing any query.

Answer (score 2):

I saw it occur on Windows 10 more than 3 times, so...
In my Windows 10 I had this problem and I deleted the file "postmaster.pid". A work brother tell me to do it and I don't know why but it solved. 
Another cause for the service don't starts is the "Warsaw" security module (used by banks), if you have installed it or something like on your machine, try uninstalling and rebooting your system. 
I hope it helps someone

Comment: This better post as a comment instead of an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)